# Spacing in Graph using LayeredDigraphEmbedding

Tags: graphs-and-networks, spacing

I currently use the following code to obtain the graph as shown. How can I change the horizontal spacing between vertices to eliminate overlap? Changing VertexSize does not help, nor does AspectRatio or ImageSize.

```
Graph[graphData, GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", 
 VertexSize -> {"Scaled", 0.02}, EdgeStyle -> Thickness[0.0004], 
 ImageSize -> Full, AspectRatio -> 1/1.5]
```

Data:

```
graphData = {1\[DirectedEdge]2,3\[DirectedEdge]2,4\[DirectedEdge]2,5\[DirectedEdge]2,6\[DirectedEdge]2,7\[DirectedEdge]2,8\[DirectedEdge]2,9\[DirectedEdge]2,10\[DirectedEdge]2,11\[DirectedEdge]2,12\[DirectedEdge]2,13\[DirectedEdge]2,1\[DirectedEdge]14,3\[DirectedEdge]14,4\[DirectedEdge]14,5\[DirectedEdge]14,6\[DirectedEdge]14,7\[DirectedEdge]14,8\[DirectedEdge]14,9\[DirectedEdge]14,10\[DirectedEdge]14,11\[DirectedEdge]14,12\[DirectedEdge]14,13\[DirectedEdge]14,2\[DirectedEdge]14,8\[DirectedEdge]15,16\[DirectedEdge]15,17\[DirectedEdge]15,18\[DirectedEdge]19,19\[DirectedEdge]8,19\[DirectedEdge]16,19\[DirectedEdge]17,20\[DirectedEdge]21,21\[DirectedEdge]22,23\[DirectedEdge]24,25\[DirectedEdge]24,22\[DirectedEdge]23,24\[DirectedEdge]8,24\[DirectedEdge]16,24\[DirectedEdge]17,26\[DirectedEdge]8,26\[DirectedEdge]16,26\[DirectedEdge]17,27\[DirectedEdge]8,27\[DirectedEdge]16,27\[DirectedEdge]17,27\[DirectedEdge]2,27\[DirectedEdge]28,29\[DirectedEdge]8,29\[DirectedEdge]16,29\[DirectedEdge]17,30\[DirectedEdge]29,31\[DirectedEdge]29,30\[DirectedEdge]8,31\[DirectedEdge]8,32\[DirectedEdge]33,32\[DirectedEdge]8,34\[DirectedEdge]28,34\[DirectedEdge]8,35\[DirectedEdge]28,36\[DirectedEdge]28,37\[DirectedEdge]28,38\[DirectedEdge]28,39\[DirectedEdge]28,28\[DirectedEdge]1,28\[DirectedEdge]3,28\[DirectedEdge]4,28\[DirectedEdge]5,28\[DirectedEdge]6,28\[DirectedEdge]7,28\[DirectedEdge]8,40\[DirectedEdge]2,40\[DirectedEdge]14,28\[DirectedEdge]16,28\[DirectedEdge]17,33\[DirectedEdge]28,33\[DirectedEdge]8,33\[DirectedEdge]29,34\[DirectedEdge]29,41\[DirectedEdge]25,21\[DirectedEdge]41,15\[DirectedEdge]42,14\[DirectedEdge]42,19\[DirectedEdge]43,28\[DirectedEdge]43,27\[DirectedEdge]43,29\[DirectedEdge]43,24\[DirectedEdge]43,26\[DirectedEdge]43,43\[DirectedEdge]15,44\[DirectedEdge]33,16\[DirectedEdge]8,16\[DirectedEdge]17,43\[DirectedEdge]8,43\[DirectedEdge]17,17\[DirectedEdge]45,17\[DirectedEdge]46,15\[DirectedEdge]45,15\[DirectedEdge]46,14\[DirectedEdge]45,14\[DirectedEdge]46,47\[DirectedEdge]17,48\[DirectedEdge]17,49\[DirectedEdge]17,50\[DirectedEdge]17,1\[DirectedEdge]17,3\[DirectedEdge]17,4\[DirectedEdge]17,5\[DirectedEdge]17,51\[DirectedEdge]17,47\[DirectedEdge]14,48\[DirectedEdge]14,49\[DirectedEdge]14,50\[DirectedEdge]14,51\[DirectedEdge]14,47\[DirectedEdge]15,48\[DirectedEdge]15,49\[DirectedEdge]15,50\[DirectedEdge]15,1\[DirectedEdge]15,3\[DirectedEdge]15,4\[DirectedEdge]15,5\[DirectedEdge]15,51\[DirectedEdge]15,40\[DirectedEdge]47,40\[DirectedEdge]48,40\[DirectedEdge]49,40\[DirectedEdge]50,40\[DirectedEdge]1,40\[DirectedEdge]3,40\[DirectedEdge]4,40\[DirectedEdge]5,40\[DirectedEdge]51,40\[DirectedEdge]17,40\[DirectedEdge]15,40\[DirectedEdge]45,40\[DirectedEdge]46,9\[DirectedEdge]47,9\[DirectedEdge]48,9\[DirectedEdge]49,9\[DirectedEdge]50,10\[DirectedEdge]47,10\[DirectedEdge]48,10\[DirectedEdge]49,10\[DirectedEdge]50,11\[DirectedEdge]47,11\[DirectedEdge]48,11\[DirectedEdge]49,11\[DirectedEdge]50,12\[DirectedEdge]47,12\[DirectedEdge]48,12\[DirectedEdge]49,12\[DirectedEdge]50,13\[DirectedEdge]47,13\[DirectedEdge]48,13\[DirectedEdge]49,13\[DirectedEdge]50,9\[DirectedEdge]1,9\[DirectedEdge]3,9\[DirectedEdge]4,9\[DirectedEdge]5,10\[DirectedEdge]1,10\[DirectedEdge]3,10\[DirectedEdge]4,10\[DirectedEdge]5,11\[DirectedEdge]1,11\[DirectedEdge]3,11\[DirectedEdge]4,11\[DirectedEdge]5,12\[DirectedEdge]1,12\[DirectedEdge]3,12\[DirectedEdge]4,12\[DirectedEdge]5,13\[DirectedEdge]1,13\[DirectedEdge]3,13\[DirectedEdge]4,13\[DirectedEdge]5,9\[DirectedEdge]51,10\[DirectedEdge]51,11\[DirectedEdge]51,12\[DirectedEdge]51,13\[DirectedEdge]51,52\[DirectedEdge]47,52\[DirectedEdge]48,52\[DirectedEdge]49,52\[DirectedEdge]50,53\[DirectedEdge]47,53\[DirectedEdge]48,53\[DirectedEdge]49,53\[DirectedEdge]50,54\[DirectedEdge]47,54\[DirectedEdge]48,54\[DirectedEdge]49,54\[DirectedEdge]50,52\[DirectedEdge]1,52\[DirectedEdge]3,52\[DirectedEdge]4,52\[DirectedEdge]5,53\[DirectedEdge]1,53\[DirectedEdge]3,53\[DirectedEdge]4,53\[DirectedEdge]5,54\[DirectedEdge]1,54\[DirectedEdge]3,54\[DirectedEdge]4,54\[DirectedEdge]5,52\[DirectedEdge]51,53\[DirectedEdge]51,54\[DirectedEdge]51,55\[DirectedEdge]47,55\[DirectedEdge]48,55\[DirectedEdge]49,55\[DirectedEdge]50,55\[DirectedEdge]1,55\[DirectedEdge]3,55\[DirectedEdge]4,55\[DirectedEdge]5,55\[DirectedEdge]51,56\[DirectedEdge]57,58\[DirectedEdge]57,59\[DirectedEdge]57,60\[DirectedEdge]57,61\[DirectedEdge]62,63\[DirectedEdge]61,63\[DirectedEdge]62,62\[DirectedEdge]57,64\[DirectedEdge]65,64\[DirectedEdge]66,67\[DirectedEdge]56,68\[DirectedEdge]56,69\[DirectedEdge]56,70\[DirectedEdge]56,71\[DirectedEdge]56,72\[DirectedEdge]56,73\[DirectedEdge]56,74\[DirectedEdge]56,67\[DirectedEdge]58,68\[DirectedEdge]58,69\[DirectedEdge]58,70\[DirectedEdge]58,71\[DirectedEdge]58,72\[DirectedEdge]58,73\[DirectedEdge]58,74\[DirectedEdge]58,67\[DirectedEdge]59,68\[DirectedEdge]59,69\[DirectedEdge]59,70\[DirectedEdge]59,71\[DirectedEdge]59,72\[DirectedEdge]59,73\[DirectedEdge]59,74\[DirectedEdge]59,67\[DirectedEdge]60,68\[DirectedEdge]60,69\[DirectedEdge]60,70\[DirectedEdge]60,71\[DirectedEdge]60,72\[DirectedEdge]60,73\[DirectedEdge]60,74\[DirectedEdge]60,75\[DirectedEdge]56,75\[DirectedEdge]58,75\[DirectedEdge]59,75\[DirectedEdge]60,76\[DirectedEdge]56,76\[DirectedEdge]58,76\[DirectedEdge]59,76\[DirectedEdge]60,66\[DirectedEdge]77,78\[DirectedEdge]77,77\[DirectedEdge]79,80\[DirectedEdge]65,66\[DirectedEdge]80,78\[DirectedEdge]80,65\[DirectedEdge]77,76\[DirectedEdge]65,45\[DirectedEdge]42,46\[DirectedEdge]42,81\[DirectedEdge]82,81\[DirectedEdge]83,81\[DirectedEdge]84,81\[DirectedEdge]85,81\[DirectedEdge]86,81\[DirectedEdge]87,81\[DirectedEdge]88,81\[DirectedEdge]89,81\[DirectedEdge]90,81\[DirectedEdge]91,57\[DirectedEdge]82,57\[DirectedEdge]83,57\[DirectedEdge]84,57\[DirectedEdge]85,57\[DirectedEdge]86,57\[DirectedEdge]87,57\[DirectedEdge]88,57\[DirectedEdge]89,57\[DirectedEdge]90,57\[DirectedEdge]91,92\[DirectedEdge]82,92\[DirectedEdge]83,92\[DirectedEdge]84,92\[DirectedEdge]85,92\[DirectedEdge]86,92\[DirectedEdge]87,92\[DirectedEdge]88,92\[DirectedEdge]89,92\[DirectedEdge]90,92\[DirectedEdge]91,65\[DirectedEdge]82,65\[DirectedEdge]83,65\[DirectedEdge]84,65\[DirectedEdge]85,65\[DirectedEdge]86,65\[DirectedEdge]87,65\[DirectedEdge]88,65\[DirectedEdge]89,65\[DirectedEdge]90,65\[DirectedEdge]91,66\[DirectedEdge]82,66\[DirectedEdge]83,66\[DirectedEdge]84,66\[DirectedEdge]85,66\[DirectedEdge]86,66\[DirectedEdge]87,66\[DirectedEdge]88,66\[DirectedEdge]89,66\[DirectedEdge]90,66\[DirectedEdge]91,78\[DirectedEdge]82,78\[DirectedEdge]83,78\[DirectedEdge]84,78\[DirectedEdge]85,78\[DirectedEdge]86,78\[DirectedEdge]87,78\[DirectedEdge]88,78\[DirectedEdge]89,78\[DirectedEdge]90,78\[DirectedEdge]91,59\[DirectedEdge]82,59\[DirectedEdge]83,59\[DirectedEdge]84,59\[DirectedEdge]85,59\[DirectedEdge]86,59\[DirectedEdge]87,59\[DirectedEdge]88,59\[DirectedEdge]89,59\[DirectedEdge]90,59\[DirectedEdge]91,56\[DirectedEdge]82,56\[DirectedEdge]83,56\[DirectedEdge]84,56\[DirectedEdge]85,56\[DirectedEdge]86,56\[DirectedEdge]87,56\[DirectedEdge]88,56\[DirectedEdge]89,56\[DirectedEdge]90,56\[DirectedEdge]91,60\[DirectedEdge]82,60\[DirectedEdge]83,60\[DirectedEdge]84,60\[DirectedEdge]85,60\[DirectedEdge]86,60\[DirectedEdge]87,60\[DirectedEdge]88,60\[DirectedEdge]89,60\[DirectedEdge]90,60\[DirectedEdge]91,81\[DirectedEdge]52,81\[DirectedEdge]53,81\[DirectedEdge]54,57\[DirectedEdge]52,57\[DirectedEdge]53,57\[DirectedEdge]54,92\[DirectedEdge]52,92\[DirectedEdge]53,92\[DirectedEdge]54,65\[DirectedEdge]52,65\[DirectedEdge]53,65\[DirectedEdge]54,66\[DirectedEdge]52,66\[DirectedEdge]53,66\[DirectedEdge]54,78\[DirectedEdge]52,78\[DirectedEdge]53,78\[DirectedEdge]54,59\[DirectedEdge]52,59\[DirectedEdge]53,59\[DirectedEdge]54,56\[DirectedEdge]52,56\[DirectedEdge]53,56\[DirectedEdge]54,60\[DirectedEdge]52,60\[DirectedEdge]53,60\[DirectedEdge]54,81\[DirectedEdge]79,57\[DirectedEdge]79,92\[DirectedEdge]79,65\[DirectedEdge]79,66\[DirectedEdge]79,78\[DirectedEdge]79,59\[DirectedEdge]79,56\[DirectedEdge]79,60\[DirectedEdge]79,82\[DirectedEdge]40,83\[DirectedEdge]40,84\[DirectedEdge]40,85\[DirectedEdge]40,86\[DirectedEdge]40,87\[DirectedEdge]40,88\[DirectedEdge]40,89\[DirectedEdge]40,90\[DirectedEdge]40,91\[DirectedEdge]40,82\[DirectedEdge]9,82\[DirectedEdge]10,82\[DirectedEdge]11,82\[DirectedEdge]12,82\[DirectedEdge]13,83\[DirectedEdge]9,83\[DirectedEdge]10,83\[DirectedEdge]11,83\[DirectedEdge]12,83\[DirectedEdge]13,84\[DirectedEdge]9,84\[DirectedEdge]10,84\[DirectedEdge]11,84\[DirectedEdge]12,84\[DirectedEdge]13,85\[DirectedEdge]9,85\[DirectedEdge]10,85\[DirectedEdge]11,85\[DirectedEdge]12,85\[DirectedEdge]13,86\[DirectedEdge]9,86\[DirectedEdge]10,86\[DirectedEdge]11,86\[DirectedEdge]12,86\[DirectedEdge]13,87\[DirectedEdge]9,87\[DirectedEdge]10,87\[DirectedEdge]11,87\[DirectedEdge]12,87\[DirectedEdge]13,88\[DirectedEdge]9,88\[DirectedEdge]10,88\[DirectedEdge]11,88\[DirectedEdge]12,88\[DirectedEdge]13,89\[DirectedEdge]9,89\[DirectedEdge]10,89\[DirectedEdge]11,89\[DirectedEdge]12,89\[DirectedEdge]13,90\[DirectedEdge]9,90\[DirectedEdge]10,90\[DirectedEdge]11,90\[DirectedEdge]12,90\[DirectedEdge]13,91\[DirectedEdge]9,91\[DirectedEdge]10,91\[DirectedEdge]11,91\[DirectedEdge]12,91\[DirectedEdge]13,82\[DirectedEdge]55,83\[DirectedEdge]55,84\[DirectedEdge]55,85\[DirectedEdge]55,86\[DirectedEdge]55,87\[DirectedEdge]55,88\[DirectedEdge]55,89\[DirectedEdge]55,90\[DirectedEdge]55,91\[DirectedEdge]55,82\[DirectedEdge]52,82\[DirectedEdge]53,82\[DirectedEdge]54,83\[DirectedEdge]52,83\[DirectedEdge]53,83\[DirectedEdge]54,84\[DirectedEdge]52,84\[DirectedEdge]53,84\[DirectedEdge]54,85\[DirectedEdge]52,85\[DirectedEdge]53,85\[DirectedEdge]54,86\[DirectedEdge]52,86\[DirectedEdge]53,86\[DirectedEdge]54,87\[DirectedEdge]52,87\[DirectedEdge]53,87\[DirectedEdge]54,88\[DirectedEdge]52,88\[DirectedEdge]53,88\[DirectedEdge]54,89\[DirectedEdge]52,89\[DirectedEdge]53,89\[DirectedEdge]54,90\[DirectedEdge]52,90\[DirectedEdge]53,90\[DirectedEdge]54,91\[DirectedEdge]52,91\[DirectedEdge]53,91\[DirectedEdge]54,79\[DirectedEdge]40,79\[DirectedEdge]9,79\[DirectedEdge]10,79\[DirectedEdge]11,79\[DirectedEdge]12,79\[DirectedEdge]13,79\[DirectedEdge]52,79\[DirectedEdge]53,79\[DirectedEdge]54,79\[DirectedEdge]55,52\[DirectedEdge]40,53\[DirectedEdge]40,54\[DirectedEdge]40,52\[DirectedEdge]9,52\[DirectedEdge]10,52\[DirectedEdge]11,52\[DirectedEdge]12,52\[DirectedEdge]13,53\[DirectedEdge]9,53\[DirectedEdge]10,53\[DirectedEdge]11,53\[DirectedEdge]12,53\[DirectedEdge]13,54\[DirectedEdge]9,54\[DirectedEdge]10,54\[DirectedEdge]11,54\[DirectedEdge]12,54\[DirectedEdge]13,52\[DirectedEdge]55,53\[DirectedEdge]55,54\[DirectedEdge]55,16\[DirectedEdge]58,43\[DirectedEdge]58,44\[DirectedEdge]58,44\[DirectedEdge]57,16\[DirectedEdge]56,43\[DirectedEdge]56,16\[DirectedEdge]79,43\[DirectedEdge]79}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your data set.

Comment: @Lexington1776
 I have added the data in the original question.

Comment: `VertexSize -> {"Scaled", 0.005}` or `VertexSize -> Offset[5]`?

Comment: @kglr this works for short labels but if the vertex labels are longer and I increase the offset or the scale the same overlap issue arises.

Answer (score 1):

This makes a pleasing graph, sans labels:

```
  Graph[graphData, GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", EdgeStyle -> Thickness[0.0004], ImageSize -> Full, AspectRatio -> 1/1.5, VertexSize -> .8, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

A couple other solutions on this forum recommended rendering the labels separately and placing them.